How to add search to the R library "collapsibleTree"
I have multiple hierarchical tree showing various org trees using "collapsibleTree" in R. This is a great package for displaying hierarchical trees, but it has no option for search. This would be very helpful as finding a person deep down in a collapsed tree is close to impossible without searching.
I tried some approaches using shiny, but non of them has worked.
I was wondering if anybody has used shiny or any other method to add search capabilities to "collapsibleTree" in R
Here is one try: I get an error in when typing into the search box.
library(shiny)
library(collapsibleTree)
library(data.tree)

# Sample data
data("acme", package = "data.tree")
acme$Do(function(node) node$cost <- sum(node$children$cost))

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Collapsible Tree Search Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("search", "Search:", value = "")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      collapsibleTreeOutput("tree")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Reactive expression to filter the tree based on search input
  filtered_tree <- reactive({
    if (input$search != "") {
      # Filter the tree using a custom function
      searchFilter <- function(node) {
        grepl(input$search, node$name, ignore.case = TRUE) || 
        any(sapply(node$children, searchFilter))
      }
      # Clone the tree and apply the filter
      filtered_acme <- acme$Clone()
      filtered_acme$Filter(searchFilter)
      return(filtered_acme)
    } else {
      return(acme)
    }
  })

  # Render the collapsibleTree
  output$tree <- renderCollapsibleTree({
    tree_data <- filtered_tree()
    if(is(tree_data, "Node")) {
      collapsibleTree(
        tree_data,
        nodeSize = "cost",
        attribute = "cost",
        tooltip = TRUE
      )
    } else {
      # If tree_data is not a Node, provide a message
      showNotification("Search did not match any nodes", type = "message")
    }
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

